# Getting values from tab-delimted file

Tags: linux, awk, cut, csv

I have a tab delimited file. In case the values contain tabs, they will enclosed in `"`. So sample records will look like this:

```
firstfield  secondfield thirdfield
firstfield  "second field   with    tab"    thirdfield
firstfield  secondfield thirdfield
```

Is it possible to write a cut/awk one liner that can take care of this situation? For example,I would like to get the second and third columns.

Comment: For these scenarios it is better to use a proper csv parser in Python or Perl

Answer (score 1):

As @fedorqui comments there are better tools than `gawk` for this task, check [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) variable anyway.

A quick `perl`solution.

```
perl -F'(\w+|"[^"]+")' -ane 'print $F[3]." ".$F[5]."\n"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk you can use the `FPAT` feature as pointed out by [klashxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1200821/klashxx):

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { FPAT = "([^\t]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
        OFS  = "\t" }
      { print $2, $3 }
```

Use it like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`. The script is adopted from [GNU Gawk manual - Splitting by content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)